# data synchronization between clients

Tags: mongodb, web-applications, redis, synchronization, database

I don't know if this is the right place to ask my question, but here it is.

Inspired by Firebase, I decided to write a little framework to synchronize data between clients. That should simplify the development of web applications such as chats, forums, etc...

Let's assume that there are one or more servers. A client can connect to one server and access a particular collection (a list of chat messages, for instance). If and when the client modifies the collection, those modifications will be sent to the other clients who requested access to the same collection.

I'd like my solution to be fast and general. The propagation of the modifications should be very fast and the collections should be persisted on a DB.
The collections may be very large but the clients may request just a view of the collection (for instance, the chat messages of the last 20 minutes).

**Possible solution**

We have n servers, 1 node with a fast in-memory DB (Redis) and a cluster with a NoSQL DB.
The cluster will contain the full collections.

When a client connects to a server and is given access to a collection for the first time, the requested part of the collection is read directly from the cluster.

When a client modifies a collection C, the modification is written to the in-memory DB which will contain something like:

- 123   added "message..."
- 124   deleted id235
- 125   modified id143 "new message..."

where 123, 124 and 125 are the versions of the collection.

In this case, the cluster contains the entire collection C and its version number which is 122.
When a client first connects to a server and accesses the collection C, the server reads the requested part of the collection from the cluster and then reads the updates from the in-memory DB in order to update the collection from version 122 to version 125.

When a client modifies the collection C,

1. the description of the modification is inserted into the in-memory DB;
2. the other servers are informed that a new version of C is available;
3. the client is sent the update.

Of course, the other servers, once informed, will send the updates to their clients as well.

Another process in the background will update the cluster the following way:

while (the in-memory database contains less than K updates for the collection C)

1. read the next update, U, from the in-memory database;
2. use U to update the collection C and its version number in the cluster ATOMICALLY.

The updates must be linearizable, i.e. no server should be able to see the collection C in a state where an update has been applied before a previous update.

When the cluster is fully-consistent, we remove the updates from the in-memory DB from lowest to highest version.

**Problem**

My solution requires a DB (for the cluster) which supports transactions (ACID?) and offers strong consistence. For instance, I can't use MongoDB.

**Question**

Can you think of a simpler solution?

or

If my solution is acceptable, what DB do you recommend for the cluster?

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

If each element of the collection is assigned a unique *id* and the updates in the in-memory DB include those ids, then one doesn't need a version number for the collection in the cluster and so transactions are unnecessary.

The idea is that the ids can be used to decide if an update is needed or not. For instance, if an update says

version=123 action=ADD id=05276 msg="Message"

and the collection in the cluster already contains a document with id=05276, then this update is old and was already applied to the collection in the cluster.

We only need to pay attention to this: before we remove some updates from the in-memory DB, we must make sure that those updates have been applied to the collection in the cluster and that the cluster is fully consistent wrt that collection.

When a client requests access to a collection, the server it connected to needs to:

1. read *all* the updates from the in-memory DB and save them in memory
2. read (the relevant part of) the collection from the cluster
3. update the read collection with the updates saved in memory

It's important to first read *all* the updates from the in-memory DB to avoid a race condition. Consider this scenario:

1. we read an old version of the collection from the cluster
2. the collection is updated
3. the cluster becomes fully consistent
4. some updates are removed from the in-memory DB
5. we update our read collection with the new updates

Problem is, in point 5 we'd miss some updates.